# WP Woocommerce is_product_category not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I am selling a single product on my woocommerce store, and beside that product I sell few accessories for him, so I want to use two templates. Next to `content-single-product.php` file I created another one called `content-single-accessory.php` and edit that template file.

Next I created two categories: product and accessory, product itself is added inside product category and accessories are added inside accessory category. Now it comes the problem I am facing with. Inside `single-product.php` I did this:

```
    <?php if (is_product_category( 'product' )) { ?>

    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

    <?php } else  { ?>

    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-accessory' ); ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

and when I visit the page with product category it does not show the product template but it shows `content-single-accessory.php`. Or to be more clear, above if statement does not work at all and second template is always showed. What I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, are you categories childrens of a parent category?

Answer (score 2):

This is good habit to try with `is_product_category()` or `is_category()` in `wordpress` but when the situation is not going in your way then don't make it complicate.

1. Get your current page url

   ```
   $current_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])
                   ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
   ```
2. And check for category page simple,

   ```
   if(strpos($current_url,'product-category') !=false
                             || strpos($current_url,'brand') !=false ) {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

pleace try this and let me know:

```
<? 
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

foreach ($terms as $term) {
   if($term->slug == 'product') : ?>

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
         <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <?php else :?>
            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-accessory' ); ?>
        <?php endif; 
}?>
```

**EDIT:**
add `<?` to the beginning

Comment: this code does not seems ok formated. This IF statement ends inside WHILE and start outside?

Comment: yes, but get the error, you didnt closed things properly

Comment: ok, tried it, same effect as without it. Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: I use this code in a clean wp installation and works